# Chef reciepe update route53 records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, chef-infra, chef-recipe, amazon-route53

I have recipe running in chef server that gets ec2 node hostname and public dns and creates cname to point hostname.mydomain.com for easier access.
I'm moving everything into the VPC and now there is no more public dns sense all in private network and uses private IP address in class A.
I need to have chef create A record instead of cname pointing to the private ip address.

Here is the recipe:

```
aws=Hash.new aws['aws_access_key_id'] = node[:base][:aws [:access_key_id] aws['aws_secret_access_key'] = node[:base][:aws][:secret_access_key] if node[:base][:aws][:route53][:update_cname_records] == true cnames = [] cnames << "#{node.name}" unless node[:base][:aws][:route53][:additional_cnames].nil? node[:base][:aws][:route53][:additional_cnames].each do |n|
  cnames << n
end end

  cnames.each do |cname|
cname_fqdn = "#{cname}.#{node[:base][:aws][:route53][:management_zone_name]}"
log ("Updating Route53 CNAME record for #{cname_fqdn}") { level :warn }

aws_route53_record "Create Route53 CNAME record for #{cname_fqdn}" do
  name  cname_fqdn
  value  node[:cloud][:public_hostname]
  type  "CNAME"
  ttl  node[:base][:aws][:route53][:ttl]
  zone_id  node[:base][:aws][:route53][:management_zone_id]
  aws_access_key  aws['aws_access_key_id']
  aws_secret_access_key  aws['aws_secret_access_key']
  action  :create
end end

else log ("NOT updating Route53 CNAME records because node[:base][:aws][:route53][:update_cname_records] = #{node[:base][:aws][:route53][:update_cname_records]}") { level :warn } end
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Are you saying that this is your old code and you need to change it?  Is this what you expected to create the Route53 record, but it doesn't work?

Comment: Correct this old code and need to change it